# Remove part of git history

Tags: git

I have a git repository which had a major branch last year.
Branch A has sub-branches for dev/staging/prod and a lot of work on it.
Branch B has only a few commits and can be archived (the product is now decomissioned).

I want to split it into two separate repositories as following:

- Branch B with whole 8 year history (for archiving).
- Branch A with all sub-branches and partial history (up until the major split, considering the split commit as the new initial commit).

What is the reccomended way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you would like to:

- have a repository containing only `branch B`. If this is so then, you can clone only a specific branch using the following command

  ```sh
  git clone your_repository --branch branch_B --single-branch 
  folder_to_put_new_local_repo_with_only_branch_B
  ```
- and then have another repository with `branch A` containing all other branches up to a revision (and except `branch B`)?

  If you know how many commit you would like to clone from the repository, you can use the following command

  ```sh
  git clone -–depth n your_repository
  ```

  `n` is the number of commits you would like to keep.

  Then you can simply delete `branch B`from this second repository using the command :

  ```sh
  git branch -d branch_B
  ```